# PostgreSQL INSERT Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: postgresql, insert, array

I have spent a few hours looking at PostgreSQL INSERT array documentation and examples.  But I am just getting more and more confused.

I've created the table `word_mash_word_cube_definitions` where column `definition` is type `text[]`.

When I created the column I used `text[][]`.  But `\d+` shows it as `text[]`.

In PHP the array is:

```
$design[1] = [ 'letter' => null , 'direction' => 'down' , 'x-axis' => 7 , 'y-axis' => 3 ];
$design[2] = [ 'letter' => null , 'direction' => 'left' , 'x-axis' => 7 , 'y-axis' => 4 ];
$design[3] = [ 'letter' => null , 'direction' => 'up' , 'x-axis' => 6 , 'y-axis' => 4 ];
$design[4] = [ 'letter' => null , 'direction' => 'left' , 'x-axis' => 6 , 'y-axis' => 3 ];
$design[5] = [ 'letter' => null , 'direction' => 'down' , 'x-axis' => 5 , 'y-axis' => 3 ];
$design[6] = [ 'letter' => null , 'direction' => 'down' , 'x-axis' => 5 , 'y-axis' => 4 ];
```

I am aiming to store the entire array in 1 row.  But I don't know if this is even possible.

Would someone please show me the correct

```
INSERT INTO word_mash_word_cube_definitions ( definition ) VALUE ( ??? )
```

I am lost.

Comment: Your data look like a perfect fit for a table. Don't make the mistake to store them as a composite type or an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to store keyed/associative arrays, then instead of a `text[]` column, use JSON. Set the column type to `jsonb`, and use `json_encode($design)` in PHP and store the resultant string. When you read the row, use `json_decode($design, true)` to turn it back into the original PHP array.

Storing it this way provides format validation and PostgreSQL functions to query inside the JSON.

There are limitations to this method, especially around character encoding, that will become important if you ever, say, add foreign language support to your app.